# Passing NULL to ({param} IS NULL OR col= {param})

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to pass NULL if query params is equal to x
but getting error

```
[Mon Feb 14 09:50:10.394841 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 11536:tid 1420] [client 104.211.153.215:55961]     cur.execute(mainQuery)\r
[Mon Feb 14 09:50:10.394841 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 11536:tid 1420] [client 104.211.153.215:55961] psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "none" does not exist\r
[Mon Feb 14 09:50:10.394841 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 11536:tid 1420] [client 104.211.153.215:55961] LINE 10:       AND (None IS NULL OR activity_group_id = None);\r
[Mon Feb 14 09:50:10.394841 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 11536:tid 1420] [client 104.211.153.215:55961]                     ^\r
[Mon Feb 14 09:50:10.394841 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 11536:tid 1420] [client 104.211.153.215:55961] \r
```

below is the function I'm running to query postgres DB

PARAMS
activityId =
if :"All" then it will give activity_group_id for all village and all activity group id
else "activity group id " pass then it will give activity_group_id for group id.

attribute = DBT category ('Farmer','FPC',NRM)
villageCode = Village Code of requested Village

```
def dbtDynamicLegend():
  
  attribute = request.args['attribute']
  activityId = request.args['activityId']
  if activityId =='All':
      activityId=None
  villageCode = request.args['villageCode']

  mainQuery =f"""SELECT DISTINCT activity_group_id,
  act."ActivityGroupCode" AS activity_group_code,
  CONCAT(act."ActivityGroupID", '_', act."ActivityGroupCode") AS "legend_id",
  activity_group_name,village_code
      FROM dbt.dbt_point_primary pnt_prm
          JOIN dbt.activity act
              ON pnt_prm.activity_group_id = act."ActivityGroupID"
                  WHERE village_code='{villageCode}' 
                  AND attributes = '{attribute}'
                  AND ({activityId} IS NULL OR activity_group_id = {activityId});"""

  with get_conn() as conn, conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(mainQuery)    
    # cur.execute(query)
    if cur.rowcount > 0:
      result = cur.fetchall()
      activity = []
      for row in result:
        activity.append({
          "activity_group_id":row[0], "activity_group_code":row[1],
          "legend_id":row[2],"activity_group_name":row[3],
          "village_code":row[4],
          })
      return flask_json.jsonify({
        'activity':activity,
        })
    else:
      return flask_json.jsonify({'err':'NO DATA FOUND'})
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: referred the manual but not worked for me.

Comment: In case you did so, please edit your question.